# Get all corresponding keys for repeated elements

Tags: arrays, perl, duplicates

I have a file which consists of following:

```
A  1
A  2
B  3
B  4
B  5
B  6
C  7
A  8
```

I want to get all unique keys in first column, but get all corresponding values for that unique key, i.e I need to get:

```
A 1,2,8
B 3,4,5,6
C 7
```

What would be the best way to do this?
(I've heard that Perl has good support to solve this, but I'm new to Perl.)

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
open my $fh, '<', "data_filename";
my %map;

while(my $line = <$fh>) {
  my ($key, $val) = split(/\s+/, $line);
  push @{$map{$key}}, $val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad for your time in answering.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a hash, where each value in the hash is an array [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

```
my %values;
while (<>) {
    my ($left, $right) = split(/ /,$_,2);
    my $array = $values{$left};
    if (!$array) {
        $array = [];
        $values{$left} = $array;
    }
    push(@{$array},$right);
}
```

You can verify that this has produced the correct data structure with [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.128/Dumper.pm):

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%values);
```

Comment: You can't create a *list* reference, you can however create an *array* reference. And no, they aren't quite the same thing.

Comment: I think you mean `if (!$array)`... but in general, this type of coding is not necessary due to Perl's autovivification of container types.  You could replace every line of the while loop below the split with `push @{$values{$left}}, $right` as erickb's example shows.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your time in answering this.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another possible solution for the sake of completeness. In this case, the hash stores a the key and a string containing your values.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash = ();
open (FILE, "input.txt") or die "";
while(FILE>){
chomp;
(my $key, my $value) = split;
    $value = ",".$value if exists $hash{$key};
    $hash{$key}.= $value;
}

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash){
    print "$key $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

As always, there's more than one way to do it.

Comment: This also wouldn't put the numbers in order though, so obviously if order is important use the anonymous array within a hash implementation.